# Async result --express, mongoose, node, bluebird, async, what have you

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, async.js

So I have this async problem wherein I use async eachSeries to iterate, findById in mongoose, then call a function within the findById...

Problem is, I can't figure out how to get the function call to resolve before it is pushed into the array, and I end up with items_results equaling an array of undefineds.

I'm new to async and to promises, so this might be a mess.

```
    var user = req.user;
    var user_items = req.user.items;
    var item_results = [];
    var queue = Promise.resolve();
    var promises = [];

    var my_iterator = function(user_item_id, callback) {
      Item.findById(user_item_id, function(err, user_item) {
        queue.then(function() {
        return outside_function(user, user_item, null, false);
        });
        promises.push(queue);
        callback();
      });
    };

    var result = function() {
      var items_object = {
          type: 'success',
          items: item_results
      };
      res.status(200).send(items_object);
    };

    async.eachSeries(user_items, my_iterator, function(err) {
       Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        item_results.push(results);
        result();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you call `queue.then()` in the callback of `outside_function`?

Comment: Maybe you should start by using either `async.js` or promises, but not both.

Comment: What is `outside_function`, where does it come from?

Comment: You probably want to do `promises.push(queue.then(…))`, not `promises.push(queue)`. `queue` is a promise that is resolved with `undefined`, which is what you are getting as `results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Promise.promisify` or `Promise.promisifyAll` on your Mongo database

```
Promise.promisifyAll(Items);

Items.findByIdAsync(user_item_id)
  .then(function (user_item) {
    res.status(200).send({
      type: 'success',
      item: user_items
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.warn(error.code);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would use.

First, make mongoose play along with bluebird.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Model);
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Model.prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Query.prototype);
```

Next, map the array of *item IDs* to an array of *item promises* and use `.all()` to wait until all pending item promises in that array have settled.

```
function middleware(req, res) {
    var pendingItems = Promise.resolve(req.user.items).map(function (id) {
        return Item.findByIdAsync(id);
    });

    return pendingItems.all().then(function (items) {
        res.status(200).send({
            type: 'success',
            items: items
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.status(200).send({
            type: 'failure',
            error: error
        });
    });
});
```